# CSS shape and text hover change color

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have looked around and cannot find an answer for this, maybe I am just making my code too convoluted.

I have a div that is making up my menu links.  The wrapper div will be a link that contains a div for my CCS Circle and a span for my link text:

```
<div class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="menu-circle"></div>
            <span class="menu-text">Home</span>
        </a>
</div>
```

I am trying to make it so that when I hover ANYWHERE over the wrapper div it changes the color of the shape AND link.  So far I have only been able to manage individual hovers on the shape OR the link.

my CSS is:

```
.menu-circle {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: black;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin:auto;
}

.menu-text{
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;
    letter-spacing: .07em;
}

.menu-circle:hover{
    background:#e7e7e7;
}

.menu-text:hover{
    color:#e7e7e7;
}

.menu-item{
    text-align:center;
}
```

you can see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9qg3vjm3/)

Comment: [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/9qg3vjm3/5/) ?

Comment: @Jonofthedead you have to select one right answer since we don't know what the exact question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the colors when you hover ANYWHERE on the wrapper div then you must call the hover state on the wrapper dive. Like this:

```
mean-item:hover .menu-circle {change colors here}
```

This however would only change the circle when hovering anywhere in the wrapper div (the wrapper being menu-item) So you would need a second hover state for menu-text

```
mean-item:hover .menu-text {change colors here}
```

See here for working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/s6jkja5r/

Comment: Well it depends on what he wants to actually accomplish. They stated they wanted to change color while hovering anywhere over the wrapper div. So maybe they want the hover stated to work in a much larger area instead of just over the elements that are changing.

Comment: Oh. I agree...that's why I said 'arguably' ;)

Comment: @GifCo this is the question `The wrapper div will be a link that contains a div for my CCS Circle`. So the wrapper is `menucircle`.

Comment: @Benjamin so the current menu-circle div you have already will be the wrapper div? or you will have another div called menucircle???

Comment: @GifCo Oops thats a typo its `menu-circle`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Funny I tried this (but tried to combine the two into one css entry) and didn't work.  Guess I didn't break them apart.  The wrapper div is part of the column grid for a bootstrap container, I would like the whole wrap (so that the space between the circle and word) triggers the hover.

Comment: @Benjamin see here for working example of color change while hovering over anywhere on the link. But the link is now only the size of the circle and the Home text. http://jsfiddle.net/wsb7k488/  I had to add an extra div as im still not exactly sure how big you want the hover area to be. But between this one and the last fiddle you should be able to sort it out.

Comment: @GifCo, Anyway to do it for longer words than home where the hover is only on the circle and the word?  example: http://jsfiddle.net/wsb7k488/2/  I attempted to expand the link section, http://jsfiddle.net/wsb7k488/1/  however you can see that the hover is also on the space to the right and left of the circle above where the words start and end...

Comment: @Jonofthedead not sure i follow? The first fiddle in your last comment does what you are asking for?? Or are you trying to get the "Value Added" all on one line???

Comment: @GifCo, trying to get the "value added" all on one line (will be using it for nav so trying to keep it as small height-wise as possible.  So i want if you cross the boundary of the circle OR you hover over the words it triggers the hover , but if you get the blank space next to the circle (which would be above the V in value added) it does NOT trigger the hover.

Comment: Hey @Jonofthedead so you need to specify a width for the menu-text item is its width is being constrained by #link element. Just adding a width wont fix this though as your menu-text is a span which is an inline element so you have to change it to block element. See here for fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/covfnjso/ Also note that i had to add some negative margin to center the text again. This can be avoided by changing you html.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your style

```
menu-circle:hover ~ .menu-text{
    color:#e7e7e7;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/9qg3vjm3/7/)**

Comment: They wanted to change colors when hovering anywhere on the wrapper div not just on the elements them self.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your css:

```
.menu-item:hover div, .menu-item:hover span {
    background:#e7e7e7;
    color:#e7e7e7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a minor CSS change.

```
.menu-item:hover .menu-circle {
    background-color: #f4f;
}

.menu-item:hover .menu-text {
    color: #f4f;
}
```

This fiddle should do exactly what you're trying to achieve:
http://jsfiddle.net/9qg3vjm3/10/

Answer (score 0):

### Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/9qg3vjm3/14/)

This changed css will change the background color of the circle div and the text color only while hovering on the circle div..

**CSS**

```
.menu-item:hover .menu-circle{
    background:#e7e7e7;
}

.menu-item:hover .menu-text{
    color:#e7e7e7;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">
       <div class="menu-circle"></div>
       <span class="menu-text">Home</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh thats not cool no one here added any additional divs here to accomplish the result.

Comment: Never mind but next make sure you answer them legibly.